# is it necessary that apps using alarm service must be installed in internal memory

Tags: android, alarm

I am developing an app which uses alarm service.
I read somewhere that apps using  alarm service must be installed in internal memory.

```
        android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

if yes , why is it so.

Does it may create any problem to phone or user.

Answer (score 1):

You should not allow your application to be installed on the external storage if it uses alarm service because  **when the external storage is unmounted-Your alarms registered with AlarmManager will be cancelled.** You must manually re-register any alarms when external storage is remounted.[See this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html)